# create-react-app: serve index.html from CDN and load right static assets after new releases

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, create-react-app, amazon-cloudfront

**Context**: When using create-react-app, and hosting it over CDN (CloudFront) + S3 (origin server), whenever a new build is generated, the built index.html refers to the static assets with updated "hash" in their filenames to handle cache busting for those assets.

**Caching**: As per create-react-app documentation, it suggests keeping the static files (js, css, media) with long-term cache expiry (Cache-Control: max-age=31536000) and for index.html: Cache-Control: no-cache.

The problem I find with this approach is, that the index.html will always be fetched from origin server (s3) and CDN is bypassed. That would incur latency, and defeat purpose of using the CDN to deliver fast page loads.

Options I have thought about, after referring to a lot of articles, but I didn't find a solution which seems ideal:

**Option 1**: Not set cache-control header on index.html on S3, and let CDN (CloudFront) serve it. Explicitly invalidate the cache for index.html on the CDN whenever a new build is deployed.

**Issue**: When a cache key is invalidated on any CDN, it may take a few minutes for all its edge servers to reflect the updated s3 object (index.html). During this time window, the browsers which get older index.html served to them from CDN, will try to download older static assets (js, css) from CDN, and in case they have a Cache Miss, CDN will try to download those assets from Origin server (S3) which are no longer present in the S3 bucket. This would lead to the App not loading for some users who run into this race condition.

**Option 2:** Eject from CRA, Generate a hashed output folder (which webpack does automatically) where all static assets are placed. Create a "version.json" file, write this output build folder's name in that json file and upload it to S3.
In index.html, have a inline script, which fetches two files:

1. /version.json
2. /asset-manifest.json
   It then parses the asset-manifest.json, to read **entrypoints**, forms the versioned urls for those entrypoint assets using value read from version.json, and inserts the script and link tags into index.html, to trigger loading of static assets.

This is the more complex route, and I could not find a reference to anyone going this route when hosting CRA-based apps over CDN, hence I felt that this approach may not be the best one to take (As it involves ejecting the cra, as well as reinventing the wheel).

Any suggestions to what could be the right way to do this? I might be mistaken in my understanding of the above problem itself, so any clarity / insights into this would be great. Thank you.